# I have this table where I have several column. Last two of them are sticky ("is-sticky" class). I want to apply some styles to the first sticky column

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass, less

```
<td> ...</td>
...
...
...
<td class="is-sticky">...</td> <-- want to apply style here
<td class="is-sticky">...</td> <-- no styles here
```

In the above code. Probably there are multiple sticky columns after the first one. But the style i want to add is only for the first column.

Comment: Just 1 row in your table?  Do any of the other rows have is-sticky td?  Should each row have the same styles applied to the first is-sticky td?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Pure CSS*** : Select every element of the class that is the sibling of the same class > invert it and select the class again.

```css
:not(.is-sticky ~ .is-sticky).is-sticky {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> .asdasd..</td>
    <td class="is-sticky">.. Frist .</td>
    <td class="is-sticky">... Second</td>
    <td class="is-sticky">... Third</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple classes to an element like this

```
<td class="is-sticky yourCSSClass">
```

Comment: Cannot do that. Since this is dynamically assigned styles based on the config in Vue. Could this be done using CSS alone?

Answer (score 0):

add another class to the first one
`"class ="is-sticky first-column"`

Then in css u can easily call to only the first column.

```
.first-column .is-sticky {
    color: white;
    etc;
}
```

Comment: Cannot do that. Since this is dynamically assigned styles based on the config in Vue. Could this be done using CSS alone?

Comment: I dont see how the first-child function in here wouldn't work. Try that maybe? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

Comment: Tried did not work. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You can use :first-child selector to style the first is-sticky of a parent differently to the ones that follow.

```css
.is-sticky:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='is-sticky'>text</div>
<div class='is-sticky'>text</div>
<div class='is-sticky'>text</div>
<div class='is-sticky'>text</div>
```

Comment: Post your answer with `table` and `td's`, I believe this solution wont work, downvoting until updated

Comment: I havent got the answer yet. So far custom class edition seems to be the way

Comment: @PreethamSridhar I have posted my answer with Pure CSS